# JVM crashes while executing swing application with native JNI code

Tags: jvm, bug-tracking, crash

My Application is using SwingWorker for executing different tasks which in turn communicating many third party DLLs, attach herewith the crash log :

Please help :

```
___________________________________________________________________
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x6d7e757a, pid=6248, tid=11036
#
# JRE version: 6.0_22-b04
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (17.1-b03 mixed mode windows-x86 )
# Problematic frame:
# C  [zip.dll+0x757a]
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x48f3e400):  JavaThread "AWT-EventQueue-0" [_thread_in_native, id=11036, stack(0x49270000,0x492c0000)]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, reading address 0xb19d9dc0

Registers:
EAX=0xcc6028cc, EBX=0x492be144, ECX=0x48be3310, EDX=0x48bd2b30
ESP=0x492be114, EBP=0x492be124, ESI=0x4902df00, EDI=0xb19d9dc0
EIP=0x6d7e757a, EFLAGS=0x00010213

Top of Stack: (sp=0x492be114)
0x492be114:   492be144 48f3e518 00000033 cc6028cc
0x492be124:   492be548 6d7e1ade 4902df00 00000000
0x492be134:   00000000 48f3e400 42ed7750 42ed7750
0x492be144:   2f6d6f63 2f6e7573 7372656a 612f7965
0x492be154:   632f6970 6e65696c 6f632f74 6769666e
0x492be164:   696c432f 43746e65 69666e6f 6c632e67
0x492be174:   2f737361 7ffdc000 7c901005 492be164
0x492be184:   00000000 492be234 7c90ee18 7c910970 

Instructions: (pc=0x6d7e757a)
0x6d7e756a:   ff ff 74 5b 8b 4e 34 8d 04 7f 8d 3c 81 8b 45 fc
0x6d7e757a:   39 07 75 3d 6a 00 56 8b c7 e8 0a fa ff ff 85 c0 


Stack: [0x49270000,0x492c0000],  sp=0x492be114,  free space=138492bdc48k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [zip.dll+0x757a]
C  [zip.dll+0x1ade]
j  java.util.zip.ZipFile.getEntry(JLjava/lang/String;Z)J+0
j  java.util.zip.ZipFile.getEntry(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/util/zip/ZipEntry;+31
j  java.util.jar.JarFile.getEntry(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/util/zip/ZipEntry;+2
j  java.util.jar.JarFile.getJarEntry(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/util/jar/JarEntry;+2
j  sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader.getResource(Ljava/lang/String;Z)Lsun/misc/Resource;+48
j  sun.misc.URLClassPath.getResource(Ljava/lang/String;Z)Lsun/misc/Resource;+53
j  java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run()Ljava/lang/Object;+26
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
V  [jvm.dll+0xf3a9c]
V  [jvm.dll+0x186591]
V  [jvm.dll+0xf3b1d]
V  [jvm.dll+0x123bdf]
C  [java.dll+0x1061]
j  java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Class;+13
j  java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Ljava/lang/String;Z)Ljava/lang/Class;+47
j  sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Ljava/lang/String;Z)Ljava/lang/Class;+41
j  java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Class;+3
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
V  [jvm.dll+0xf3a9c]
V  [jvm.dll+0x186591]
V  [jvm.dll+0xf3c67]
V  [jvm.dll+0xf3d5a]
V  [jvm.dll+0x1cbe98]
V  [jvm.dll+0x1cc3bd]
V  [jvm.dll+0x1cc775]
V  [jvm.dll+0x1cc7bb]
V  [jvm.dll+0x1f2b0b]
V  [jvm.dll+0x1b93a1]
V  [jvm.dll+0x1b9499]
V  [jvm.dll+0x1b94f2]
V  [jvm.dll+0x1b9d25]
V  [jvm.dll+0x1f74ff]
V  [jvm.dll+0x1f80da]
V  [jvm.dll+0x1f81d8]
V  [jvm.dll+0xdb992]
V  [jvm.dll+0xe0c19]
V  [jvm.dll+0xe213a]
V  [jvm.dll+0xe37e4]
V  [jvm.dll+0xe3bd2]
V  [jvm.dll+0xeedb3]
j  in.gov.uidai.auth.app.SampleClientMainFrame.authenticateRequest(Lin/gov/uidai/auth/app/AuthenticationRequestData;)Z+79
j  in.gov.uidai.auth.app.SampleClientMainFrame.authenticateActionPerformed(Ljava/awt/event/ActionEvent;)V+291
j  in.gov.uidai.auth.app.SampleClientMainFrame.access$22(Lin/gov/uidai/auth/app/SampleClientMainFrame;Ljava/awt/event/ActionEvent;)V+2
j  in.gov.uidai.auth.app.SampleClientMainFrame$24.actionPerformed(Ljava/awt/event/ActionEvent;)V+5
j  javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Ljava/awt/event/ActionEvent;)V+84
j  javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Ljava/awt/event/ActionEvent;)V+5
j  javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Ljava/awt/event/ActionEvent;)V+35
j  javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Z)V+117
j  javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Ljava/awt/event/MouseEvent;)V+35
j  java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Ljava/awt/event/MouseEvent;)V+64
j  javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Ljava/awt/event/MouseEvent;)V+23
j  java.awt.Component.processEvent(Ljava/awt/AWTEvent;)V+81
j  java.awt.Container.processEvent(Ljava/awt/AWTEvent;)V+18
j  java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Ljava/awt/AWTEvent;)V+566
j  java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Ljava/awt/AWTEvent;)V+42
J  java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Ljava/awt/Component;ILjava/awt/event/MouseEvent;)V
j  java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Ljava/awt/event/MouseEvent;)Z+139
j  java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Ljava/awt/AWTEvent;)Z+50
j  java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Ljava/awt/AWTEvent;)V+12
j  java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Ljava/awt/AWTEvent;)V+19
j  java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Ljava/awt/AWTEvent;)V+2
j  java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Ljava/awt/AWTEvent;)V+46
J  java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(I)Z
j  java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(ILjava/awt/Conditional;Ljava/awt/EventFilter;)V+30
j  java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(ILjava/awt/Conditional;Ljava/awt/Component;)V+11
j  java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(ILjava/awt/Conditional;)V+4
j  java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Ljava/awt/Conditional;)V+3
j  java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run()V+9
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
V  [jvm.dll+0xf3a9c]
V  [jvm.dll+0x186591]
V  [jvm.dll+0xf3c67]
V  [jvm.dll+0xf3cdd]
V  [jvm.dll+0x11da00]
V  [jvm.dll+0x1e7004]
V  [jvm.dll+0x185f3c]
C  [msvcr71.dll+0x9565]
C  [kernel32.dll+0xb50b]

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  java.util.zip.ZipFile.getEntry(JLjava/lang/String;Z)J+0
j  java.util.zip.ZipFile.getEntry(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/util/zip/ZipEntry;+31
j  java.util.jar.JarFile.getEntry(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/util/zip/ZipEntry;+2
j  java.util.jar.JarFile.getJarEntry(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/util/jar/JarEntry;+2
j  sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader.getResource(Ljava/lang/String;Z)Lsun/misc/Resource;+48
j  sun.misc.URLClassPath.getResource(Ljava/lang/String;Z)Lsun/misc/Resource;+53
j  java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run()Ljava/lang/Object;+26
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
j  java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Ljava/security/PrivilegedExceptionAction;Ljava/security/AccessControlContext;)Ljava/lang/Object;+0
j  java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Class;+13
j  java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Ljava/lang/String;Z)Ljava/lang/Class;+47
j  sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Ljava/lang/String;Z)Ljava/lang/Class;+41
j  java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Class;+3
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
j  in.gov.uidai.auth.app.SampleClientMainFrame.authenticateRequest(Lin/gov/uidai/auth/app/AuthenticationRequestData;)Z+79
j  in.gov.uidai.auth.app.SampleClientMainFrame.authenticateActionPerformed(Ljava/awt/event/ActionEvent;)V+291
j  in.gov.uidai.auth.app.SampleClientMainFrame.access$22(Lin/gov/uidai/auth/app/SampleClientMainFrame;Ljava/awt/event/ActionEvent;)V+2
j  in.gov.uidai.auth.app.SampleClientMainFrame$24.actionPerformed(Ljava/awt/event/ActionEvent;)V+5
j  javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Ljava/awt/event/ActionEvent;)V+84
j  javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Ljava/awt/event/ActionEvent;)V+5
j  javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Ljava/awt/event/ActionEvent;)V+35
j  javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Z)V+117
j  javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Ljava/awt/event/MouseEvent;)V+35
j  java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Ljava/awt/event/MouseEvent;)V+64
j  javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Ljava/awt/event/MouseEvent;)V+23
j  java.awt.Component.processEvent(Ljava/awt/AWTEvent;)V+81
j  java.awt.Container.processEvent(Ljava/awt/AWTEvent;)V+18
j  java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Ljava/awt/AWTEvent;)V+566
j  java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Ljava/awt/AWTEvent;)V+42
J  java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Ljava/awt/Component;ILjava/awt/event/MouseEvent;)V
j  java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Ljava/awt/event/MouseEvent;)Z+139
j  java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Ljava/awt/AWTEvent;)Z+50
j  java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Ljava/awt/AWTEvent;)V+12
j  java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Ljava/awt/AWTEvent;)V+19
j  java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Ljava/awt/AWTEvent;)V+2
j  java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Ljava/awt/AWTEvent;)V+46
J  java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(I)Z
j  java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(ILjava/awt/Conditional;Ljava/awt/EventFilter;)V+30
j  java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(ILjava/awt/Conditional;Ljava/awt/Component;)V+11
j  java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(ILjava/awt/Conditional;)V+4
j  java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Ljava/awt/Conditional;)V+3
j  java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run()V+9
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x48f8a800 JavaThread "TimerQueue" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4896, stack(0x49300000,0x49350000)]
  0x00396c00 JavaThread "DestroyJavaVM" [_thread_blocked, id=11620, stack(0x003b0000,0x00400000)]
=>0x48f3e400 JavaThread "AWT-EventQueue-0" [_thread_in_native, id=11036, stack(0x49270000,0x492c0000)]
  0x48f38400 JavaThread "AWT-Windows" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=8820, stack(0x491e0000,0x49230000)]
  0x48f36c00 JavaThread "AWT-Shutdown" [_thread_blocked, id=10752, stack(0x49190000,0x491e0000)]
  0x48f35c00 JavaThread "Java2D Disposer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9764, stack(0x49140000,0x49190000)]
  0x48bbec00 JavaThread "Low Memory Detector" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=8260, stack(0x48e10000,0x48e60000)]
  0x48bbac00 JavaThread "CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=10148, stack(0x48dc0000,0x48e10000)]
  0x48bb7800 JavaThread "Attach Listener" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=10980, stack(0x48d70000,0x48dc0000)]
  0x48bb6000 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=11532, stack(0x48d20000,0x48d70000)]
  0x48ba8400 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=11320, stack(0x48cd0000,0x48d20000)]
  0x48ba3800 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=11248, stack(0x48c80000,0x48cd0000)]

Other Threads:
  0x48ba0c00 VMThread [stack: 0x48c30000,0x48c80000] [id=10420]
  0x48bc9c00 WatcherThread [stack: 0x48e60000,0x48eb0000] [id=11204]

VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

Heap
 def new generation   total 7808K, used 886K [0x02970000, 0x031e0000, 0x17ec0000)
  eden space 6976K,  12% used [0x02970000, 0x02a4db10, 0x03040000)
  from space 832K,   0% used [0x03040000, 0x03040000, 0x03110000)
  to   space 832K,   0% used [0x03110000, 0x03110000, 0x031e0000)
 tenured generation   total 17244K, used 8155K [0x17ec0000, 0x18f97000, 0x42970000)
   the space 17244K,  47% used [0x17ec0000, 0x186b6de0, 0x186b6e00, 0x18f97000)
 compacting perm gen  total 12288K, used 10210K [0x42970000, 0x43570000, 0x46970000)
   the space 12288K,  83% used [0x42970000, 0x433688f8, 0x43368a00, 0x43570000)
No shared spaces configured.

Dynamic libraries:
0x00400000 - 0x00424000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\javaw.exe
0x7c900000 - 0x7c9b0000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\ntdll.dll
0x7c800000 - 0x7c8f4000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\kernel32.dll
0x77dd0000 - 0x77e6b000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\ADVAPI32.dll
0x77e70000 - 0x77f01000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\RPCRT4.dll
0x77d40000 - 0x77dd0000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\USER32.dll
0x77f10000 - 0x77f56000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\GDI32.dll
0x7c340000 - 0x7c396000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\msvcr71.dll
0x6d7f0000 - 0x6da97000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\client\jvm.dll
0x76b40000 - 0x76b6d000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\WINMM.dll
0x6d7a0000 - 0x6d7ac000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\verify.dll
0x6d320000 - 0x6d33f000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\java.dll
0x6d280000 - 0x6d288000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\hpi.dll
0x76bf0000 - 0x76bfb000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\PSAPI.DLL
0x6d7e0000 - 0x6d7ef000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\zip.dll
0x6d000000 - 0x6d14a000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\awt.dll
0x73000000 - 0x73026000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\WINSPOOL.DRV
0x77c10000 - 0x77c68000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\msvcrt.dll
0x76390000 - 0x763ad000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\IMM32.dll
0x774e0000 - 0x7761c000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\ole32.dll
0x773d0000 - 0x774d2000     C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\x86_Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.2600.2180_x-ww_a84f1ff9\COMCTL32.dll
0x77f60000 - 0x77fd6000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\SHLWAPI.dll
0x5ad70000 - 0x5ada8000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\uxtheme.dll
0x74720000 - 0x7476b000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\MSCTF.dll
0x7c9c0000 - 0x7d1d4000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\shell32.dll
0x6d230000 - 0x6d27f000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\fontmanager.dll
0x6d600000 - 0x6d613000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\net.dll
0x71ab0000 - 0x71ac7000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\WS2_32.dll
0x71aa0000 - 0x71aa8000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\WS2HELP.dll
0x6d620000 - 0x6d629000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\nio.dll
0x6d440000 - 0x6d465000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\jpeg.dll
0x77120000 - 0x771ac000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\OLEAUT32.DLL
0x49960000 - 0x499a3000     C:\FingerprintSensors\Morpho-CBM\Mso_SpUsb.dll
0x49450000 - 0x4946f000     C:\FingerprintSensors\Secugen-HFDU04\SGFPLIB.DLL
0x77c00000 - 0x77c08000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\VERSION.dll
0x76c30000 - 0x76c5e000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\WINTRUST.dll
0x77a80000 - 0x77b14000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\CRYPT32.dll
0x77b20000 - 0x77b32000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\MSASN1.dll
0x76c90000 - 0x76cb8000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\IMAGEHLP.dll
0x49890000 - 0x498b8000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\rsaenh.dll
0x769c0000 - 0x76a73000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\USERENV.dll
0x5b860000 - 0x5b8b4000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\netapi32.dll
0x71a50000 - 0x71a8f000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\mswsock.dll
0x76f20000 - 0x76f47000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\DNSAPI.dll
0x76fb0000 - 0x76fb8000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\winrnr.dll
0x76f60000 - 0x76f8c000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\WLDAP32.dll
0x76fc0000 - 0x76fc6000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\rasadhlp.dll
0x662b0000 - 0x66308000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\hnetcfg.dll
0x71a90000 - 0x71a98000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\wshtcpip.dll

VM Arguments:
jvm_args: -Xmx1024m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 
java_command: in.gov.uidai.auth.app.SampleClientMainFrame
Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

Environment Variables:
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_22
CLASSPATH=C:\Program Files\Novosoft\C2J\Bin\c2jruntime.zip;
PATH=C:\FingerprintSensors\Suprema-BioMiniPlus;C:\FingerprintSensors\Morpho-CBM;C:\FingerprintSensors\Secugen-HFDU04;C:\FingerprintSensors\Secugen-HFDU04\;
USERNAME=admin
OS=Windows_NT
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=x86 Family 6 Model 23 Stepping 10, GenuineIntel



---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS: Windows XP Build 2600 Service Pack 2

CPU:total 2 (2 cores per cpu, 1 threads per core) family 6 model 23 stepping 10, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3

Memory: 4k page, physical 2060716k(771808k free), swap 3999436k(2553396k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (17.1-b03) for windows-x86 JRE (1.6.0_22-b04), built on Sep 15 2010 00:56:36 by "java_re" with MS VC++ 7.1 (VS2003)

time: Wed May 11 19:58:57 2011
elapsed time: 36 seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

This thread is about the same issue

[Java swing UI crash debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/378754/java-swing-ui-crash-debugging)

Answer (score 0):

From the stack trace, it is crashing while attempting to load a Java class from a jar file. This could be caused by a corrupt jar file, or a jar file being modified in another thread or application while being read.